# Lock element to bottom of containing div

Tags: html, css

```
#Container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
}

#TheElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

How do i get #TheElement to be locked to the very bottom of #Container, regardless of the other content inside container, without a bunch of margin trickery?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can use [relative absolute positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/):

http://jsfiddle.net/gzJM6/

```
#Container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative
}

#TheElement {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing i tried, but it dosent work for some reason

Comment: Check my jsFiddle, it seems to work fine. Could you provide more detail about your situation?

Comment: Oh... i missed the relative positioning on the #Container. It works now.  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, that's important as `position: absolute` is in fact relative to the closest parent element that has been `position`ed.